# Docker run to execute script in mount without exiting container automatically?

Tags: bash, docker, rstudio-server

I have a simple bash script 'test.sh' in the root of mounted folder :

```
#!/bin/bash
Rscript -e "source('/home/rstudio/mount-folder/src/controller.R')";
```

However, when i try to mount folder and start the container with docker run as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8787 -e ROOT=true -e DISABLE_AUTH=true --name container -v mount-folder/:/home/rstudio/ image_name /home/rstudio/test.sh
```

above run command starts the container but exits automatically.

I am looking for a docker run command that starts the container , mounts the folder and then executes the bash script which is in the mount-folder without exiting the container.

(** dont want to go with docker exec command as it is not suitable for my use case for other reasons)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/rstudio:4.0.2

//some RUN commands to install necessary r packages

EXPOSE 8787

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Other details :

1. Image that i am using is rstudio server from rocker and container runs on AWS ubuntu machine.

Edit :

1. have also tried adding CMD tail -f /dev/null at the end of dockerfile as suggested in http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/07/how-to-keep-docker-containers-running/ even then the container exits.

Comment: it can exit on error from your `set -e`   if bash is not on that path for example on rstudio image.

Comment: I would expect that invocation to run the script you name on the `docker run` command line, and when that script completes, the container exits.  If that's not what you want, what should the container do after the script is done?

Comment: @DavidMaze the idea behind running this bash script is to execute other R script (you can see it in attached bash) which basically sets up global variables in rstudio server which is my image. I need the rstudio server to hang around so that other developers can work on the server without having to worry about the global variables

Comment: Put your full command in the Dockerfile instead of the "docker run ..." statement. Like this - `CMD /home/rstudio/test.sh && tail -f /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers shutdown automatically when run in detached mode. I think this article proposes a nice solution:

http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/07/how-to-keep-docker-containers-running/

You could add `tail -f /dev/null` as the last command in your bash script instead so that the script will never halt unless it is told to do so.

Comment: have tried adding 'CMD tail -f /dev/null' at the end of dockerfile even then the container seems to exit.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `docker run [options] image_name [cmd]` the command you specify becomes the command for the container and replaces any the command specified in the dockerfile (that's why adding `CMD tail -f /dev/null` doesn't do anything). If you ran your container without the `/home/rstudio/test.sh` at the end, it should stay running.

The solution would be to update your script to add the `tail` command at the end.

```
#!/bin/bash
Rscript -e "source('/home/rstudio/mount-folder/src/controller.R')";
exec tail -f /dev/null
```

If you can't update that script, you could instead add it to the command being passed to the container, with something like:
`docker run [options] image_name bash -c '/home/rstudio/test.sh && exec tail -f /dev/null'`